# Mongo connector not synchronizing data between mongodb and elastic search

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, integration

I am trying to use mongo connector to import the data from mongo db to elastic search. I have followed the instructions as given in the link:

https://github.com/10gen-labs/mongo-connector/wiki/Usage-with-ElasticSearch
mongo db
: 2.4.12
connector version:2.0.3
elastic search version: 1.5.2

We are having issue where the data is not being imported from mongodb to elastic search.

Queries:

1. What is the best way to integrate mongodb with elastic search and synchronize real time data between them in production
2. How to setup the synchronization-steps
3. How to create one time indexes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mongo-db-river` plugin to sync the data from `mongoDB` to `elasticsearch`the following refernce link will give you the more detail about the river plugin.

[MongoDB River Plugin](https://github.com/richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb/wiki) 
[Reference](https://github.com/richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb/#mongodb-river-plugin-for-elasticsearch)

if you need more help on this please ask.

Comment: Can we customize data flow b/w mongo db and elastic search based on collection or column?

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use mongo connector, what your question are answered:
http://blog.mongodb.org/post/29127828146/introducing-mongo-connector
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/5-way-sync-data-from-mongodb-es-kai-hao

just like:
[root@5b9dbaaa1 bin]# mongo-connector -m 10.18.15.99:27017 -t 10.18.15.11:9200 -d elastic2_doc_manager
Logging to mongo-connector.log.

Comment: Reference links are fine, but it would be better if you provide a summary of the information that is focused on answering the question.